# Replacing existing column with values based on condition from other values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to replace values from my table with values from query result. The query looks like this:

```
select *,
    case
        when car_model = 'Altima' THEN 'Nissan'
        when car_model = 'F-150' THEN 'Ford'
        when car_model = 'Civic' THEN 'Honda'
        when car_model = 'Silverado' THEN 'Chevrolet'
    END
FROM car_sales_data
WHERE car_model IN ('Altima','F-150','Civic','Silverado')
```

Basically, this is data cleaning task to do. I am working on it for few hours now and I can't come to any working solution...

**Important thing is that I want these new values to be saved in a table so I can do some analysis afterwards.
**

I've tried different things like INSERT INTO, creating table, none of it worked for me. I am a beginner :)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update car_sales_data
set car_model=
case
        when car_model = 'Altima' THEN 'Nissan'
        when car_model = 'F-150' THEN 'Ford'
        when car_model = 'Civic' THEN 'Honda'
        when car_model = 'Silverado' THEN 'Chevrolet'
        else car_model
    END

WHERE car_model IN ('Altima','F-150','Civic','Silverado')
```

Base Data

```
   create table car_sales_data(car_model varchar(100))
insert into car_sales_data values('Altima')
insert into car_sales_data values('F-150')
insert into car_sales_data values('Civic')
insert into car_sales_data values('Civic')
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below will check if your results table exists, and drop it if so (to allow multiple runs). It then selects the required data into `dbo.test` from your current table, and select the results. I've set it to put the results into a table called `dbo.test`; make sure this name isn't in use already for something else.

```
/* DELETE OUTPUT TABLE IF IT EXISTS */

if exists
(
    select name from sys.tables 
    where 
        name = 'test' 
        and OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_ID) = 'dbo'
)
begin 
    drop table dbo.test 
end

select *,
    case
        when car_model = 'Altima' THEN 'Nissan'
        when car_model = 'F-150' THEN 'Ford'
        when car_model = 'Civic' THEN 'Honda'
        when car_model = 'Silverado' THEN 'Chevrolet'
    END

/*  NEW table NAME HERE */

into dbo.test

FROM car_sales_data
WHERE car_model IN ('Altima','F-150','Civic','Silverado')

select * from dbo.test
```